# Materalize framework, parallax doesn't work

Tags: css, django, frameworks

i'm using Parallax, but it doesn't work

```
      <div class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax"><img src="{% static "img/mdd.jpg" %}"></div>
      </div>
```

class parallax hide the img. The path is ok, (using Django). If I use

```
      <div class="parallax-container">
        <img src="{% static "img/mdd.jpg" %}">
      </div>
```

it works, but I'm not using parallax class, so I wouldn't have parallax function.

help? thanks

css

```
.parallax-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px; }

.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1; }
  .parallax img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translateX(-50%); }
```

Comment: What does _"class parallax hide the img."_ mean? Does DOM contain `<img>`?

Comment: I don't know. Im just using MATERIALIZE framework. I edit the question, and paste .css parallax class.